# How to edit text file and remove value?

Tags: .net, vb.net, vb.net-2010

I have two text files. The fields in each text file are separated by a space (" "). Some of the fields in column 1 of file 1 match the fields in column 1 of file 2. However the third column in file 2 is a numeric field.  What I wish to do is check every field in file1 against the field in file 2, and if the number is 1 then remove the row from file 2, if the number is > 1, then subtract one from it.

I have the following coding so far.

```
Dim lines1 As New List(Of String)(IO.File.ReadAllLines("File1"))
Dim lines2 As New List(Of String)(IO.File.ReadAllLines("File2"))

Dim values As New Dictionary(Of String, Integer)()
For Each line As String In lines1
    Dim fields() As String = line.Split(ControlChars.Tab)
    If fields.Length > 1 Then
        values(fields(0)) = Integer.Parse(fields(1))
    End If
Next

For Each line As String In lines2
    Dim fields() As String = line.Split(ControlChars.Tab)
    If fields.Length > 0 Then
        If values.ContainsKey(fields(0)) > 1 Then
            values(fields(0)) = values(fields(0)) - 1
        Else
            values.remove(fields(0))
        End If
    End If
Next

lines1.Clear()
For Each pair As KeyValuePair(Of String, Integer) In values
    lines1.Add(pair.Key + ControlChars.Tab + pair.Value.ToString())
Next

IO.File.WriteAllLines("File2", lines1.ToArray)
```

For example

```
File1

String1 String 
String2 String
String5 String
String8 String

File2

String1 String 6
String2 String 8
String3 String 2
String4 String 2
String5 String 1
String6 String 4
String7 String 8
String8 String 1
```

After my code has ran

```
File1

String1 String 
String2 String
String5 String
String8 String

File2

String1 String 5
String2 String 7
String3 String 2
String4 String 2
String6 String 4
String7 String 8
```

Comment: If this is a homework assignment, you should add the homework tag.

Comment: Homework? I left school 10 years ago :/ plus vb is not my strongest skills, so I'm taking each day at a time.

Comment: That's no problem. There are several problems with your code, though. I'll try to take a look at it later today if nobody else has.

Comment: Could you explain what problem do you have? I see some errors in your code, but I don't know if they are only typos or are your real problem

Answer (score 1):

Some parsing fun here... just Dim out strFile1Path and strFile2Path with their respective file paths and let this code handle the rest.  Hopefully the code and comments will teach you some tricks.

```
    Dim lstFile1Contents As New List(Of String)(IO.File.ReadAllLines(strFile1Path))
    Dim lstFile2Contents As New List(Of String)(IO.File.ReadAllLines(strFile2Path))

    Dim sbNewFile2Contents As New System.Text.StringBuilder

    For Each strLineToProcess As String In lstFile2Contents

        'Trim off trailing spaces for processing.
        strLineToProcess = Trim(strLineToProcess)

        Dim strCheckForMatch As String = strLineToProcess.Substring(0, (InStr(strLineToProcess, " ") - 1))

        Dim bolFoundMatch As Boolean = False
        Dim intCursor As Integer = 0
        Do Until intCursor = lstFile1Contents.Count OrElse bolFoundMatch

            If lstFile1Contents(intCursor).Substring(0, (InStr(lstFile1Contents(intCursor), " ") - 1)) = strCheckForMatch Then

                bolFoundMatch = True

                'We found a match, so let's check the third field.
                Dim intNumber As Integer = CInt(strLineToProcess.Substring((strLineToProcess.LastIndexOf(" ") + 1), (Len(strLineToProcess) - (strLineToProcess.LastIndexOf(" ") + 1))))

                If intNumber > 1 Then

                    'Subtract one from the third field.
                    sbNewFile2Contents.AppendLine(strLineToProcess.Substring(0, (strLineToProcess.LastIndexOf(" ") + 1)) & (intNumber - 1).ToString())

                End If

            End If

            intCursor += 1

        Loop

        If Not bolFoundMatch Then

            'No match was found, so make sure the line remains unedited.
            sbNewFile2Contents.AppendLine(strLineToProcess)

        End If

    Next

    'Finally write the file contents.
    IO.File.WriteAllText(strFile2Path, sbNewFile2Contents.ToString())
```